# Output the least appearing item using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, find, ddl

There is a table called song which has these attributes-

song(songID: integer, songName: string, genre: string, year: integer)

I am supposed to list the genres for which there are lowest number of songs. The output should be genre and cannot contain duplicates.

I have to find this output using min and without out using Min. Currently stuck on finding it through the use of min.

Any starter help?

I am starting off with this

```
select MIN(genre)
from song;
Where song.id<=ALL
 (select songID
  from song);
```

But all this gives me is the first alphabetical genre it gets.

Additional info, SongID is primary key but I doubt that matters.

Comment: that's nice of you to tell us.   Good luck with your homework!  However stackoverflow is for questions, and you haven't asked one :)

Comment: I think this site become StackOverHomework

Comment: I just need help on how to start approaching this as min is confusing me.

Comment: what have you tried?  way better on here is to paste some code of what confuses you and ask Why doesn't this work?

Comment: HINT for non MIN, 'ORDER BY' 'TOP'

Answer (score 0):

You can get a count for each genre like so:

```
SELECT genre, count(*) FROM song GROUP BY genre;
```

From there, you'll probably want to read up on commands such as `MIN()`, `LIMIT`, `ORDER BY`, and the like. Google around for examples and tutorials.